# Exclude NULL and Numeric values from Array

Tags: php, arrays, array-filter

Here is an array which contains Integer and NULL values. I want to exclude these two things from the array and print the rest.

I am using array_filter() using callback. But there is something wrong with it. I could not figure out the real issue for hours.

Please help me figure out.

Here is the code.

```
 <?php 
   function remove_elem($var) { 
    return($var & is_numeric($var[0]) & ' '); 
   }
 ?>


<?php 
  $a1=array(1,'Programming','Design','Marketing',' ',' ');
  print_r(array_filter($a1,"remove_elem"));
?>
```

**Thank You!**

Comment: note that a string with a single space `' '` and `NULL` are two completely different values. what do you want to do exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your remove_ele function has issue.

Use this it will work fine.

```
function remove_elem($var) { 
   return $var != " " && !is_numeric($var);
}

$a1=array(1,'Programming','Design','Marketing',' ',' ');
print_r(array_filter($a1,"remove_elem"));
```